# How to print a string from an actual printer on Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, printing

I want to send a string to a printer from an iPad using code.

The trouble is, I want to connect to the printer using wifi, and then send a string to it for printing. But I don't know how to connect to the printer, and how to send the string, hope someone can help me. Thanks.

The printer and the iPad are in the same local area off-line, I want to use the socket to transfer the content that I want to print through the IP address of the printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the printer is configured as an AirPrinter then it's fairly easy using [UIPrintInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/).

Comment: This is the best way to do this. If you want to print to a printer that does not supply AirPrint, then good luck getting the information here. There are entire apps dedicated to only printing things. (Such as the HP Printer App)

Comment: i'm a new leaner,could you introduction more detailed?thank you

Comment: @edision -- Then presumably you know all about sockets.  Problem solved!